# Adding icons to IOS App in Cordova CLI 6.3.1

Tags: cordova, icons, config

I am creating an app in IOS and android in cordova cli 6.3.1.

I am not getting the app icon displayed in IOS but working fine in android.

Here is my config

My APP
    
        My APP

```
<content src="index.html" />

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="4.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="1.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="1.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />

<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
<preference name="backgroundColor" value="#c72678" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="false" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="deployment-target" value="6.1" />

<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <splash src="images/splashscreen/android/800x1280.png" />
    <splash src="images/splashscreen/android/200x300.png"  platform="android" qualifier="ldpi" />
    <splash src="images/splashscreen/android/307x480.png"  platform="android" qualifier="mdpi" />
    <splash src="images/splashscreen/android/480x800.png"  platform="android" qualifier="hdpi" />
    <splash src="images/splashscreen/android/720x1280.png" platform="android" qualifier="xhdpi" />
    <splash src="images/splashscreen/android/720x1280.png" platform="android" qualifier="fr-xhdpi" />
    <icon src="images/icon.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform> 
<config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="UIStatusBarHidden">
           <true/>
</config-file>
<config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance">
       <false/>
</config-file>

<!-- iPhone and iPod touch -->
<splash src="images/splashscreen/ios/320x480.png" platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />


<!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
<splash src="images/splashscreen/ios/640x1136.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />

<!-- iPhone 6 -->
<splash src="images/splashscreen/ios/750x1334.png" platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
<splash src="images/splashscreen/ios/1242x2208.png" platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208" />


<!-- iPad -->
<splash src="images/splashscreen/ios/768x1024.png" platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />


<!-- Retina iPad -->
<splash src="images/splashscreen/ios/1536x2048.png" platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />


<!-- iPad -->
<icon src="images/icon_76x76.png" platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />




<!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
<icon src="images/icon_57x57.png" platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />


<!-- iPad -->
<icon src="images/icon_72x72.png" platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
```

The icon images are there in specified folder.

Can anyone hep me in sorting out the issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably missing the right icon size. Currently these are all the icons iOS requires.

```
<platform name="ios">
        <icon height="57" src="res/icons/icon-57.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="res/icons/icon-114.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="72" src="res/icons/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="res/icons/icon-144.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="res/icons/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="res/icons/icon-152.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="40" src="res/icons/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="res/icons/icon-80.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="50" src="res/icons/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="res/icons/icon-100.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="120" src="res/icons/icon-120.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="res/icons/icon-180.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="29" src="res/icons/icon-29.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="res/icons/icon-58.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="res/icons/icon-87.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="167" src="res/icons/icon-167.png" width="167" />
</platform>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That was the exact solution.

Comment: You just saved my life. 14 hours of frustration and dead ends. Thank you so much.  Question:  Adding this to my config.xml appears to address all the icon needs for our app. Does this mean that the cordova-icon plugin is no longer required?

Comment: @Rjak Do you mean the cordova-icon script?  You'll still need to create the icons somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For cordova with iOS and change icon and splash image, the simplest way is:

1. Having a 1024 icon for better quality Process for iOS all sizes with
   [pgicons.abiro.com](http://pgicons.abiro.com)
2. Get zip uncompressed and copy to the root directory of the project.
3. Finally edit from root directory the config.xml and include or create the code generated by the web online.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following scripts that auto-generate icons and splashscreens for Cordova using ImageMagick:

https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-icon

https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-splash