# Apple rejects app built with Xcode 8 even though I have included the icons it claims are missing

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, icons

This app was built with Cordova 6.3.1 and the icons were generated with cordova-icon. I do not think any of that is relevant, however.

I have included an image which clearly describes the problem and my confusion: Apple rejects our binary saying that we are missing 57x57 and 72x72 icons, which those icons are clearly present in the project.

[image]

For @pedrouan: Here is a screenshot of the directory created by the build process. I should mention that we have been building with these tools for years, including a release last month. These rejections are new, which is what leads me to believe they are specific to iOS 10. I do not recall seeing an Images.xcassets in the Xcode project, but it looks like the build process definitely adds the directory.

[image]

Edit 2 for @pedrouan:  Here is what the assets look like when added to the Xcode project. I am going to try to submit this and see if that is the new step required now.

[image]

Edit 3 for @pedrouan: The AppIcon section now looks exactly as it should. Apple is still rejecting the binary.

[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your `Assets.xcassets` -> `App Icon` catalog? I guess you miss it some way, because you wouldn't have icon files stored like you have right now, on the left.

Comment: @pedrouan Since this is a Cordova-built app, it does not use an Asset Catalog. I believe Assets.xcassets only exists in the project if you are using an Asset Catalog, correct?  We have no Assets.xcassets in the project AFAICT.

Comment: I don't know Cordova, but try to check whether paths are properly set, as Cordova generated code is responsible for handling icons.

Comment: @pedrouan Do you know if there is any beginner documentation about AssetCatalogs? Apple has no documentation I can find that describes how to create one, only how to use a previously existing one.

Comment: @pedrouan ARGH! I just learned that there *IS* an AssetCatalog. It is a side effect of the cordova build process that it is not displayed in the Xcode project. I will add a screenshot of the directory to the original post.

Comment: Well check according to some hints in my answer below, whether that Asset catalogue is not missing any icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Cordova builds, attempting to address this with manual Asset Catalog creation is a dead end. The actual solution to this problem is addressed in the accepted answer to this question:

[Adding icons to IOS App in Cordova CLI 6.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663167/adding-icons-to-ios-app-in-cordova-cli-6-3-1)

It appears that the cordova-icon plugin may no longer be required.

Answer (score -1):

I see that there are five complains about icons within that email from Apple. That signs, there is something wrong with all of your icons prescription.

I guess this will not work for Apple. I would go Assets catalogue way in all cases. (Even though I understand, that you would need to do this each time you generate the product)

Quick guide:

[image]

Source: http://guides.codepath.com/ios/Adding-Image-Assets

[image]

For help, look at the App Icon section on this link: http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev10510b1f7

Comment: I have added the already-existing Images.xcassets to the Xcode project now. Updated my original question with yet another screenshot which shows all the icons are there.

Comment: On your screenshot, I see Not assigned. That's the issue. Look on an attached image in my updated answer.

Comment: That's how it should look like.

Comment: @pedroaun I have defined the AppIcon section of the Images.xcassets exactly as described. Apple still rejects the binary with exactly the same message (all the same missing required and recommended files). Attached a new screenshot to the original question.

Comment: Finally, check whether you have set Asset Catalogue as a source for App Icons. http://pasteboard.co/9ORTvVofB.png

Comment: You can find it at Target -> General -> App Icons and Launch Images

Comment: Yeah I found that, and now when I launch the app on my device my iPhone6 Plus displays the app at non-retina resolution. I'm going crazy!!!  Thanks SO much for your help so far @pedrouan.

Comment: You should use also Launch screen, actually there are many possible combinations. But this belongs to another queston I guess. It's a mess :)

Comment: @Rjak Did my answer help you at least a bit?

Comment: You definitely helped me learn a lot about how to manually create and manage Asset Catalogues in Xcode for projects that are not procedurally generated by Cordova. Thank you very much for giving me that understanding, I very much appreciate it! In terms of this specific question regarding a Cordova build, the answer I referenced is definitely the correct choice. I just realized that I did not mention Cordova in the original question (side effect of working dozens of overtime hours last week without a break), so that's definitely my fault. Thank you SO much for your assistance!!!

Comment: I haven't received any vote or acceptation, so that's why I asked. Glad to help. Next time I can be even faster in understanding.